# Change where statement to exclude duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that I use to import orders into a survey software's database. Currently it imports all the orders from the previous day, but recent changes in business plan requires these surveys to be sent out hourly.  The imports come from a view in a different database. attribute 1 is the order number, which will be unique per survey so we can use that to limit the imports.

How do I change this to not pull in duplicates?

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Insert INTO SurveyTable
(SurveyTable.firstname,
SurveyTable.token,
SurveyTable.email,
SurveyTable.emailstatus, 
SurveyTable.language, 
SurveyTable.remindersent, 
SurveyTable.attribute_1,
SurveyTable.attribute_2)


select 
    location,
    cast( '' as xml ).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column( "token" ) )', 'nvarchar(MAX)' ),
    email,
    emailstatus, 
    [language],
    remindersent,
    attribute_1,
    attribute_2
from 
    (
        select 
            RTRIM([Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Location]) location,
            crypt_gen_random(12) as token, 
            [Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Email] email,
            'OK' emailstatus,
            'en' [language], 
            'N' remindersent, 
           [Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Order Number] attribute_1, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Invoice Date],110) attribute_2 
        from 
            [Closed_Orders_For_Survey]
        where 
            [Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Order Date] >= dateadd(DAY, -1, Convert(date, GETDATE()))
    ) as x
END
```

P.S. the token is a generated unique string used in creaating the survey URL. We decided not to use the order number as the token because this would be too predictable and enable people to change their url to fill out other users surveys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not perfectly optimal for very large data sets (you'd want to make sure you have good indexes on attribute_1), but you can do a 'where not exists' clause to filter out any orders from the inner query that already have been inserted:

```
select 
    location,
    cast( '' as xml ).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column( "token" ) )', 'nvarchar(MAX)' ),
    email,
    emailstatus, 
    [language],
    remindersent,
    attribute_1,
    attribute_2
from 
    (
        select 
            RTRIM([Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Location]) location,
            crypt_gen_random(12) as token, 
            [Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Email] email,
            'OK' emailstatus,
            'en' [language], 
            'N' remindersent, 
           [Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Order Number] attribute_1, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Invoice Date],110) attribute_2 
        from 
            [Closed_Orders_For_Survey]
        where 
            [Closed_Orders_For_Survey].[Order Date] >= dateadd(DAY, -1, Convert(date, GETDATE()))
    ) as x
where 
    not exists (
        select attribute_1 
            from SurveyTable 
            where 
                attribute_1 = x.attribute_1
        )
```

Comment: will this work even if the originating view holds the invoice number as char and the destination as nvarchar?

Comment: It should, since the char strings are being cast to nvarchar when they are inserted anyway, they should cast on the compare the same way.

Comment: For whatever reason it's still pulling in most of the rows from the view (which are all already imported) There are 6k+ rows in the view and 5140 are coming back in this query.

Comment: OK. How would I go about sending that over?

Comment: You could update your question with a few rows from each table (maybe two orders from each, with one order being the same in both, and one unique to each).

Comment: Actually I figured out why there were so many coming back. The not exists you constructed works. The ones that were still showing up were in fact not in the survey table. They were just old orders prior to when we set up the survey, as well as orders that were missed by my original SP (because of poor programming\scheduling) I marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem silly, but if the token is a primary key, then the attempt to insert a duplicate token will sinply fail.  Trap that specific error in your application (and vigorously ignore it) and you're golden.

If it must be all one transaction, you can always add a "and token not in (select token from table)" subselect (potentially inefficient, but should work).